# BindingExpression path error - when trying to bind the textbox to the view model

Tags: c#

I keep getting the following error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'TabToAdd' property not found on 'object' "ManageTabViewModel"; target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String').
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'TabbableViewModel' property not found on 'object'
>   "ManageTabsViewModel".
>
> BindingExpression:Path=TabbableViewModel;DataItem='ManageTabViewModel';
>   target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is
>   'DataContext' (type 'Object').

This happens whenever I am trying to bind the textbox to the view model. This is my code so far:

**ManageTabsViewModel.xaml**

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding TabbableViewModel}" Text="{Binding Path=TabsToAdd}" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,6"></TextBox>
```

**ManageTabsViewModel.cs**

```
public class TabbableViewModel: ITabbableViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ITabbable Tabbable {get; set};
    public IEnumerable<ITabViewModel> Tabs { get; set }
    private IEnumerable<string> _tabsToAdd;
    public IEnumerable<string> TabsToAdd
    {
        get { return _tabsToAdd }
        set 
        {
            if(Equals(value, _tabsToAdd))
                return;
            _tabsToAdd = value
            OnPropertyChanged("TabsToAdd");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public interface ITabbable 
{
    IEnumerable<string> TabsToAdd { get; set; }
}

public interface ITabbableViewModel 
{
    ITabbable Tabbable { get; set; }
}

public class ManageTabsViewModel : IManageTabsViewModel 
{
    public void SetTabbable(IEnumerable<ITabbable> tabbable) 
    {
        TabbableItems = tabbable;
        ExpandedTabbableItems = (from t in TabbableItems
                                 from u in t.Tabs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new TabbableViewModel() 
                                 {
                                    Tabbable = t,
                                    Tabs = t.Tabs,
                                    TabsToAdd = t.TabsToAdd
                                 }).ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITabbableViewModel> ExpandedTabbableItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ITabbable> TabbableItems { get; set; }
}

public interface IManageTabsViewModel 
{
    void SetTabbable(IEnumerable<ITabbable> tabbable);
    IEnumerable<ITabbable> TabbableItems { get; }
    IEnumerable<ITabbableViewModel> ExpandedTabbableItems { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to a class, which doesn't make any sense -- you need to bind to a specific instance of the class.

In addition, you bind `TextBox.Text` to `TabToAdd`; this looks like it should be `TabsToAdd` -- the actual name of a property (note missing **s**).

If you look at this message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TabbableViewModel' property not found on 'object' "ManageTabsViewModel".

...it seems clear that you already have a `ManageTabsViewModel` as your `DataContext`. That means you can access the properties of `ManageTabsViewModel`, if that makes sense. The closest thing `ManageTabsViewModel` has to a `TabbableViewModel` is the `IEnumerable` `TabbableItems`, meaning something like

```
TabbableItems[0]
```

might make sense.

The `TabsToAdd` property, which you're trying to bind to `TextBox.Text`, is also an `IEnumerable`,  so I don't rightly know what you expect to show in the text box -- it will likely be the class name, produced by `IEnumerable.ToString`. (You could change this to, say, a comma-separated list of strings through a converter, though.) Or you could bind to `TabsToAdd[0]` to get the first one (or, if the list is empty, an error).

The `TextBox` inherits its `DataContext` from its parent. You can set it to whatever from code-behind, though. Give it a name in the XAML:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="textBox"
    Text="{Binding Path=TabsToAdd}"
    Width="250"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="6,0,0,6" />
```

In the code-behind constructor, assign the DataContext:

```
textBox.DataContext = ... // Some object whose properties you'll bind to
```

It's a bit hard to see what you're aiming for, as the code is incomplete -- if you can reduce this to the simplest possible example of your problem, it would be easier to advise.

Comment: Hi Petter thanks for getting back to me. I've updated the typo in the code. I do not understand what you mean by binding TextBox to a specific instance of the class, can you please show me a code example of what you mean? I've been struggling with this issue for a week.

Comment: Does that mean I have to move `IEnumerable<string> TabsToAdd` from TabbableViewModel to ManageTabsViewModel?

Comment: I expanded on my answer. I don't fully understand your data structure or what you're hoping to achieve, so I can't say whether you need to move anything. You have a fairly large number of interfaces and classes here...